# Jenkins/Hudson - Cannot build multimodule project

Tags: java, maven, build, hudson, jenkins

I'm trying to set up my Jenkins to build my project. The root module was built without a problem. But now when the other module needs the root one, Jenkins throws this exception

```
Parsing POMs
ERROR: Failed to parse POMs
org.apache.maven.project.ProjectBuildingException: Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM: Failure to find cz.cvut.fit.wst:wst-root-pom:pom:1.0 in http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 3, column 10

    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:363)
    at hudson.maven.MavenEmbedder.buildProjects(MavenEmbedder.java:361)
    at hudson.maven.MavenEmbedder.readProjects(MavenEmbedder.java:331)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$PomParser.invoke(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:1224)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$PomParser.invoke(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:1049)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:832)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:814)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$RunnerImpl.parsePoms(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:914)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$RunnerImpl.doRun(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:658)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.run(AbstractBuild.java:473)
    at hudson.model.Run.run(Run.java:1410)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:481)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:238)
Finished: FAILURE
```

It seems that it doesn't look for artifacts in my local repository. How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you checked your pom's based on the error message "forced and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 3, column 10"

Comment: Remove $M2_HOME/repository/cz/cvut/fit/wst directory (M2_HOME dependence on your build configuration, default is ~/jenkins/.m2)

Answer (score 0):

parent.relativePath is not mandatory, and can be a bit confusing in several cases (in jenkins/hudson, but in IDE as well).

So unless you have a good reason to rely on the relativePath, I consider it simpler to install the parent POM and access it like any other dependency (I use NEXUS as a corporate repo, and the jenkins local maven gets the last version of the parent POM from it if necessary)

Comment: FYI, I believe in Maven3, relativePath is by default ".." and you have to explicitly set it to <relativePath/> to turn it off.